# Are forests and trees considered self sufficient and self reliant? Or is there any lore on caretakers of the forests?

Tags: symbolism, yggdrasil, world-tree

With the significance of trees as representations of life in various cultures, do any of them ever mention caretakers of the forests? Or a defense against impurities and corruption?

Or have they always been considered everlasting, near indestructible symbols of life?

(What follows is not important, it's just the result of what hidden triggers can shoot out of you)

I guess in the time of mythology the forests almost never ended, even if they did near the sea or a mountain,  it would start up again sooner or later.

Nowadays, the forest is just a thing we let the smart people worry about.

Comment: Can you specify what you are trying to ask? It is very unclear.

Comment: Are there any caretakers of the forest or is it self reliant

Answer (score 5):

Well, I know that with the Ancient Celts the tree of life was a big thing to their culture, to the extent they believed they were trees, or came from trees. They saw them as the symbol for balance, and would leave a big tree to stay on their land because of their beliefs that they were magic (as they provided a multitude of uses such as food and medicine); because of this, cutting down a tree of life was seen as an offense.
So in a way, the Celts were kind of like caretakers of the trees, but not necessarily forests.

According to a bit of further research, I've found somewhat indirect answers to your questions.
The trees were also seen as a symbol for rebirth and long life, because they lose and regrow their leaves each year. So everlasting, yes I guess you could say that. As for indestructible, that's debatable.
It's also said that the trees were a gateway to the spirit world; that the tree of life's roots connect to the world below, while it's branches connect to the world above and it's trunk is the link that connects both of them to the Earth, which is how the Celts supposedly communicated with the gods. In this sense, I would personally say that it's safe to assume it can be a defense against impurities and corruption, especially when you factor in medicine being available from trees.

Answer (score 5):

To the [ancient Celts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Celtic_religion), certain trees, especially the oak, ash and thorn, held special significance.

> To the Celts, Druids and many other peoples of the old world, certain trees held special significance as a fuel for heat, cooking, building materials and weaponry. In addition to this however, many woods also provided a powerful spiritual presence. The specific trees varied between different cultures and geographic locations, but those believed to be "sacred" shared certain traits. Unusual size, beauty, the wide range of materials they provided, unique physical characteristics, or simply the power of the tree's spirit could grant it a central place in the folklore and mythology of a culture. <sub>[wicca site](https://wicca.com/celtic/celtic/sactrees.htm)</sub>

Oak has been considered sacred by the Celts because of its size, longevity, and [nutritious acorns](https://www.reference.com/food/acorns-edible-5d17e8f70c3fb223). The oak was the "King of Trees" in a grove.